# Django recursive query on non-symmetrical Many-to-Many to the same model

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I'm offering services to companies (many-to-many between `Service` and `Company`). To structure my services, I use a tree-like structure using Django's many-to-many field. So, a service can contain multiple other services.

The question: how can I retrieve all services a company has? Using `company.services`, I only get the services directly related to that company. I need the directly related ones + included_services (in a recursive way).

```
class Company(models.Model):
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)

class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    included_services = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using Django's ORM framework or writing a plain raw `SQL` statement. You might want to take a look at 3rd party libraries like [`django-mptt`](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) that enables you to store/retrieve models represented in tree-like structures more efficiently.

However, if you want to do it via Python, here is what you can do:

```
def get_services(company):
    services = list(company.services.all())
    result = []
    while services:
        service = services.pop(0)
        result.append(service)
        services.extend(list(service.included_services.all()))
    return result
```

The above idea is very similar to performing a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) in a tree.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! I had a recursive solution, but this breadth-first search is a more readable approach.

Comment: With this approach you need to be careful that you don't introduce any cycles in your services graph, otherwise this will run in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I needed a QuerySet as return value, so I modified @ozgur's exellent answer a bit. Just in case someone also needs this:

```
def get_services(company):
    services = list(company.services.all())
    pks = []
    while services:
        service = services.pop(0)
        if service.pk not in pks:
            pks.append(service.pk)
            services.extend(list(service.included_services.all()))
    return Service.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)
```

EDIT: I also added a check for potential loops.